# Text is not displayed in "SourceList" Outline View

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nstablecellview

I am using a "SourceList" OutlineView and cannot get the content of the "header" and "data" NSTableCellViews to display. The structure of the OutlineView works and my app runs and looks similar to this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E4D8.png.

Here is my code:

```
- (id)init {
            self = [super init];
            if (self) {
                _masterFolder = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                MasterFolder *trueMaster = [[MasterFolder alloc] initMaster:@"Categories"];

                [_masterFolder addObject:trueMaster];
                [trueMaster addChild:[[MasterFolder alloc] initMaster:@"World"]];
                [trueMaster addChild:[[MasterFolder alloc] initMaster:@"Sports"]];
                [trueMaster addChild:[[MasterFolder alloc] initMaster:@"Local"]];
                [trueMaster addChild:[[MasterFolder alloc] initMaster:@"Business"]];

                [(MasterFolder *)[trueMaster.children objectAtIndex:0] addChild:[[MasterFolder alloc] initMaster:@"Middle East"]];
            }
            return self;
    }


    - (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item {
        return !item ? [self.masterFolder count] : [[item children] count];
    }

    - (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item {
        return !item ? YES : [[item children] count] != 0;
    }

    - (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item {
        return !item ? [self.masterFolder objectAtIndex:index] : [[item children] objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    - (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
        if (![item isKindOfClass:[MasterFolder class]]) {
            return [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell" owner:self];
        } else {
            NSTableCellView *cellView = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"DataCell" owner:self];
            cellView.textField.stringValue = [((MasterFolder *)item) name];
            return cellView;
        }
    }
```

I know it is an issue with this function:

```
    - (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
```

but I do not know what to change to make it work. I have viewed a lot of similar posts on Stack Overflow already, and was not able to get the solutions that were offered to work.

Comment: Any hints to what the problem was?